# porque aparece dos veces cada viewController que entro en my app ios despues del launch?

Tags: ios, swift

bueno les cuento que lo que tengo.
tengo un appa que en el appDelegate verifico si ha iniciado sesion antes o si no ha iniciado sesion antes, lo hago para que despues del launcherViewcontroller pueda verificar eso. y todo funciona perfectamente pero el problema es cuando ya entro ya sea bien al loginViewcontroller o al mainViewcontroller de acuerdo a si inicio sesion o no.
el problema esque cuando empiezo a navegar por la app por ejemplo presionar un boton que me lleve a otro viewController este viewController me aparece dos veces es decir se carga dos veces y asi es en cada viewController que entro en TODA la app y la verdad no entiendo porque me pasa eso muchas gracias.

aqui dejo mi codigo que esta en el AppDelegate:

```
 var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

  var window: UIWindow?

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
   [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    var viewcontroller : UIViewController!
    if((AppUserDefaults.userDefaultsForKey(key: .logged)) != nil){
        let log = AppUserDefaults.userDefaultsForKey(key: .logged) as! 
        Bool

        if(log){

         viewcontroller = 
     storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
      "ViewController1") 
        as! ViewController

        }else{

          viewcontroller = 
    storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        }

    }else{
       viewcontroller = 
    storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
   "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

    }
    let navigationcontroller = 
     UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)
    navigationcontroller.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationcontroller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle =   
    UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    //        let handler: LookyLooCountryHandler = 
    LookyLooCountryHandler()
    //        handler.prepareDataBace()


    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    return true
}
```

me olvidaba de comentar que cuando el quito todo este codigo que contiene  el metodo `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  funciona todo correctamente es decir ya no aparece doble viewController cada vez que navego por la app al presionar botones , gracias amigos.

Comment: usa breakPoints uno en cada if y else y pues sería que verificaras que es lo que esta haciendo...

Comment: Puedes poner el código del View Controller que se repite y utilizas segues para llamarlo o por código?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que en el proyecto tengas configurado un Storyboard como Main Interfaz, por lo que lanzará la primer pantalla del storyboard al principio. Luego por codigo estas remplazando el rootViewController y eso causa que la pantalla se lanze dos veces.
Quita el StoryBoard del MainInterfaz, deja el campo vacio y no deberias tener mas ese problema.